# Jest | Testing Utility Function that accepts multiple parameters

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, jestjs

I have created this utility. It takes 3 parameters, (value: string, service: any `which is an actual service(GET)`, name: string).

Here is the utility:

```js
import { serverErrorResponseUtil } from 'util/serverErrorResponseUtil';
import { HttpError } from 'factories/httpFactory';

const validateUniqueName = (value: string, service: any, name: string): string =>
  service()
    .then(({ data }: { data: object }) => {
      if (Array.isArray(data) && data.find(resourceData => resourceData.name === value)) {
        throw new Error(`${name} already exists`);
      }
    })
    .catch((error: HttpError) => {
      throw serverErrorResponseUtil(error);
    });

export default validateUniqueName;
```

I am trying to test that utility, but since I need to accept the `service` as a parameter, along with `value, name` I am kind of perplexed on how to do it.

Here is what I did:

```js
import validateUniqueName from '../validateUniqueName';
import validationRules from '../__mocks__/validationRules';

jest.mock('../__mocks__/services.ts');

describe('validateUniqueName', () => {
  let validateUniqueNameFn: Function = jest.fn();
  beforeEach(() => {
    validateUniqueNameFn = validateUniqueName;
  });
  it('should THROW an error if the given value already exists', () => {});
  it('should ACCEPT the data if the pass name is unique', () => {});
});
```

And those 2 are the case scenarios I want to cover. Can you help me a bit. Just some guides will be good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

`validateUniqueName.ts`:

```js
import { serverErrorResponseUtil, HttpError } from './serverErrorResponseUtil';

const validateUniqueName = (value: string, service: any, name: string): string =>
  service()
    .then(({ data }: { data: object }) => {
      if (Array.isArray(data) && data.find(resourceData => resourceData.name === value)) {
        throw new Error(`${name} already exists`);
      }
    })
    .catch((error: HttpError) => {
      throw serverErrorResponseUtil(error);
    });

export default validateUniqueName;
```

`serverErrorResponseUtil.ts`:

```js
export interface HttpError {
  message: string;
}

export function serverErrorResponseUtil(error: HttpError) {
  return new Error(error.message);
}
```

`validateUniqueName.spec.ts`:

```js
import validateUniqueName from './validateUniqueName';
import { serverErrorResponseUtil } from './serverErrorResponseUtil';

jest.mock('./serverErrorResponseUtil.ts', () => {
  return {
    serverErrorResponseUtil: jest.fn()
  };
});

describe('validateUniqueName', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('should THROW an error if the given value already exists', async () => {
    const responseMocked = { data: [{ name: 'someValue' }] };
    const serviceMocked = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(responseMocked);
    await expect(validateUniqueName('someValue', serviceMocked, 'someName')).rejects.toBeUndefined();
    expect(serverErrorResponseUtil).toBeCalledWith(new Error('someName already exists'));
  });

  it('should ACCEPT the data if the pass name is unique', async () => {
    const responseMocked = { data: [{ name: 'jest' }] };
    const serviceMocked = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(responseMocked);
    await expect(validateUniqueName('ts', serviceMocked, 'someName')).resolves.toBeUndefined();
    expect(serverErrorResponseUtil).not.toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/56847791/validateUniqueName.spec.ts
  validateUniqueName
    ✓ should THROW an error if the given value already exists (6ms)
    ✓ should ACCEPT the data if the pass name is unique (1ms)

-----------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                   |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files              |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 validateUniqueName.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.688s, estimated 8s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/56847791